# FabricJS - disable panning viewport -x -y axis

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, panning

if the mouse goes out of canvas and mouse move in -x -y axis , I want disable pan.
how can i disable viewpoint -x -y axis.

this is my code.

```
var panning = false;
canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
    if (isPaningMode) {
        panning = false;
    }
});
canvas.on('mouse:out', function (e) {
    if (isPaningMode) {
        panning = false;
    }
});
canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
    if (isPaningMode) {
        panning = true;
    }
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
    canvas.selection = !isPaningMode;
    if (isPaningMode && e && e.e && panning) {
        var units = 10;
        var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
        canvas.relativePan(delta);
    }
});
```

Thank you, sorry i cant speak english well. :(

**Edit**

[image]

my canvas is size : 800x800 
I just want to use the red striped area. I do not want to use sections with X. I do not want them to be shown by scrolling in these fields. I did what I said for the objects. But I could not do it for panning. In short, I want to panning only in the direction of the arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest version of FabricJS, they are continually improving it.  I noticed in the past that `canvas.on('mouse:out')` was targeting objects and not the canvas.

Here's a working JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/bvgLvd3u/.

[image]

I'm assuming this was the issue because you were already disabling panning on mouse-out of the canvas.

```
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e) {
  if (isPaningMode) {
    panning = false;
  }
});
```

Let me know if I miss understood your English - which is very good, by-the-way!

**After Your Edit**

Bulk of the change is in the mouse-move event.  *In summary:* Keeping track of the distance moved so we know where we started from, to get back to (with a tweak, if needed) - hope that makes sense???

```
var deltaX = 0;
var deltaY = 0;
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
  if (isPaningMode && e && e.e && panning) {
    moveX = e.e.movementX;
    if (deltaX >= 0) {
      deltaX -= moveX;
      if (deltaX < 0) {
        moveX = deltaX + moveX;
        deltaX = 0;
      }
    }
    moveY = e.e.movementY;
    if (deltaY >= 0) {
      deltaY -= moveY;
      if (deltaY < 0) {
        moveY = deltaY + moveY;
        deltaY = 0;
      }
    }
    if (deltaX >= 0 && deltaY >= 0) {
      canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(moveX, moveY));
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a new, updated, and working :) JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/r3gm3uh9/.

Comment: First of all thank you for helping me :). It was one of my wishes. I add my other problems to the editing section.

Comment: @forguta Fixed your other problems, I believe.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, @TimHarker. I really respect you very much.:) Finally, there is another problem under another heading. I'm very happy if you can look. :)